# Django 2.2 : How to change verbose_name of default auth app "Authentication and Authorization"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-authentication

How can change `verbose_name` of default auth app in Django Admin, by default it's showing `Authentication and Authorization`. I just want rename this with `Staff Management`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change `verbose_name` but you can use can try [django-modeladmin-reorder](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder) which is great to rename Admin models.